# Protobuff serialise System.Numerics.BigInteger

Tags: c#, serialization, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

The code:

```
[ProtoMember(11002)]
public BigInteger StartInteger { get; private set; }
```

Throws the exception:

```
No serializer defined for type: System.Numerics.BigInteger
```

How can I make `StartInteger` serialisable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to solve this by doing:

```
public BigInteger StartInteger { get; private set; }
[ProtoMember(11002, DataFormat = DataFormat.FixedSize)]
private byte[] StartIntegerSerialized
{
    get { return StartInteger.ToByteArray(); }
    set { StartInteger = new BigInteger(value); }
}
```